# search option for users

Tags: feature-request, users

I think, it would be nice if we have search option for users so that we can search on a particular word or topic within te users questions/answers

Answer (score 3):

You can already do this to a certain extent.

Use the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search) in the top right search box:

For example searching for this on SO

`user:51529 splint`

[Gives you these results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:51529+splint)

Comment: Barry, how about searching for posts of several users?